# Is there a way to embed a `\r` or even a `\n` to send over telnet in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port, telnet

I am trying to send RS232 commands embedded within telnet data for a video over IP device. It works perfectly using Tera Term and windows command prompt telnet but it's not working using Python (telnetlib)

[Using Tera Term, it works fine:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFE1.jpg)

[Correct Result (Fan status of 3 fans) MCU responds Correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGaV0.jpg)

However, when I use Python's Telnet library:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT,timeout = 3)
tn.write('send '+ DEVICE_MAC + ' rs232:1 get_fan ?\r')
```

HOST,PORT and DEVICE_MAC are all defined in my original code. 
For some reason, \r is not sent to the HOST.

```
get_fan ?\r
```

`\r` is needed for the HOST MCU to properly process the `get_fan ?` command but the Python code above only sends `get_fan ?` without the `\r`.

Is there a way to embed a `\r` or even a `\n` to send over telnet? 
I am looking for clues in telnetlib.py, but perhaps the solution is simpler. I would appreciate your comments if possible. Thanks!

Comment: If I got it right you want to send/pass `get_fan ?\r` to the command `send <some_mac> rs232:1` ... if so, try wrapping it in between single quotes also you could take in consideration to escape the `\r` in `\\r`. If you wanted to "just hit <key>enter</key>", try using "\n". Except some few models of router pretty much every telnet server I've encountered used the "default" telnet newline which is "\n".

Comment: Hi Lohmar. Thank you for your comment. I see your point and I totally take your point. The problem is that once telnetlib.py sees a "\n" in the data to be sent, it interprets this to send the telnet data (or flush.()) the socket (i think).  I swear, I've been stressing over this for a few days and I just found the solution. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this is to use the "string literal" concept. I just ran into the clue on this link https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

The correct code I should have used from the start is:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT,timeout = 3)
tn.write('send '+ DEVICE_MAC + ' rs232:1 get_fan ?' + r'\r' + '\r\n')
```

I used `+` concatenation for clarity only, but adding `r` before `'\r'` prevents the carriage return from being interpreted as a telnet escape sequence and thus it is sent as a string in the telnet data. The second carriage return and line feed `\r\n` is definitely needed to be interpreted as an escape sequence to flush the socket and send the telnet data.